# Returning Linq query results into a List object (based on condition)

Tags: linq

I need to return a number of Linq query results into a List object based on a foreign key value. What is the syntax for doing this? I am new to using Linq, so below is my best guess so far. I receive an error in the .Where() "clause" stating "The name 'pt' does not exist in the current context. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
        List<AgentProductTraining> productTraining = new List<AgentProductTraining>();

        var prodCodes = productTraining.Select(pt => new[]
                                                         {
                                                             pt.ProductCode,
                                                             pt.NoteId,
                                                             pt.ControlId
                                                         })
                                                         .Where(pt.CourseCode == course.CourseCode);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to switch the locations of where and select if you're using extension methods:

```
var prodCodes = productTraining.Where(pt => pt.CourseCode == course.CourseCode)
                               .Select(pt => new SomeRandomType
                                                         {
                                                             ProductCode = pt.ProductCode,
                                                             NoteId = pt.NoteId,
                                                             ControlId = pt.ControlId
                                                         });
```

I also recommend, as you can see above, that you create a type for that select statement so that you're not relying on anonymous types. You should put in into an object type that you know everything about.

Also, if CourseCode is a string, that should be `pt.CourseCode.Equals(course.CourseCode)`.

Comment: Hm... anytime I define SomeRandomType (I've tried string and AgentProductTraining so far), it immediately begins throwing an error over ProductCode, NoteId, and ControlId. The message says: 'ProductCode' does not exists in the current context, 'NoteId' does not... etc.

Comment: That's because you need to create a new object class that houses those fields. By doing so you will avoid the dangers of using anonymous types.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without creating a new object class? I only need it for this part of the program, so it would seem a little cumbersome to break out a new class library for just this alone.

Comment: You can just do it with an anonymous type by removing the SomeRandomType above. I automatically create an object class so that I don't have to worry about using anonymous types.